# .ready not acknowledging AJAX content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am loading content, mostly images, through this ajax call, and would like to fade the div in only when all of the images are completely loaded. For this reason, I thought that I should use .ready, so that all of the content was loaded before I use jquery to fade it in, but for some reason the images are not completely loaded when the div gets faded in, which makes it seem like it is not waiting for everything to load.

I am basically wanting to build a preload, for this AJAX content

```
function getPage() {
    var data = 'page=' + encodeURIComponent(document.location.hash);

    $.ajax({
        url: "loader.php",  
        type: "GET",        
        data: data,     
        cache: true,
        success: function (html) {  


            $('#content').html(html);
            $("#slider").easySlider();  

            $(this).ready(function() {

                 $('#body').fadeIn('slow');
                 $('#loader').fadeOut('slow');

             });




        }       
    });
```

Thank you for the help in advance. I am still a beginner.

example:

Comment: On your example it seems the behaviour is the one intended. Could you please provide extra-details?

Comment: The problem is that the user will be able to see the images loading in after the section is selected. I want the images to already be loaded before the div is faded in. Maybe this is the wrong way to do that though. Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:
Oh, now I see what's your problem!

When the success() function is fired, you gotta add a .load event to the images inside #content!

You gotta do something like this

```
function getPage() {
    var data = 'page=' + encodeURIComponent(document.location.hash);
    $('#loader').fadeIn('slow');
    $.ajax({
        url: "loader.php",  
        type: "GET",        
        data: data,     
        cache: true,
        success: function (html) {  

            $('#content').html(html);
            $("#slider").easySlider();  
            $('#content img').load(function(){
                 $('#body').fadeIn('slow');
                 $('#loader').fadeOut('slow');
            });
        }       
    });
}
```

Comment: Try the new solution, please.

Comment: Thank you again for the answer. Maybe this is another question all together, but I reference a dynamic div that is called with ajax with prevents me from referencing the images directly. The images are in every case inside of the #slider div. I tried the following load function.... $('#slider').load(function(){...etc.. and it never gets inside the function. Thanks again for the help. I am not sure if that confuses things even more, or makes them easier.

Comment: I believe only 1 the is displayed when the slider loads, so maybe you should try $("#slider img:first").load(function(){})

Comment: The problem is that each case is going to pass a different first image. So it looks like this...
and there are going to be like 10 cases... Thanks again for bearing with me.

Comment: No problem, this code works in every case. Try it and post a demo.

Comment: For some reason, I see the click event in the [rel='ajax'] a tags is calling getPage() twice, and the first time it's sending an empty value for $_GET['page']. Your content isn't showing up at all because it is being cleared from the #content div.